# Apps Hungarian for modern Windows API projects?

Tags: winapi, hungarian-notation

Since answers to similar questions only go as far as to make the distinction between apps and systems Hungarian - is there any comprehensive list of apps Hungarian prefixes that could be used to maintain consistency between Windows API identifiers and the rest of my code?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/stg/coding-style-conventions

Answer (score 0):

Hungarian notation is the practice of adding prefixes to the names of variables, to give additional information about the variable. The C++ Core Guidelines discourage prefix notation (for example, Hungarian notation).Internally, the Windows team no longer uses it. But its use remains in samples and documentation.

The notation was conceived to allow you to know the type of the variable, but modern environments have seriously mitigated the need for this. It means that you can avoid having to do this.However, as for whether using Hungarian notation in your code depends on yourself.

For more details about comprehensive list of apps Hungarian prefixes, I suggest you could refer to:[Coding Style Conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/stg/coding-style-conventions) ,[Windows Coding Conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/windows-coding-conventions) and [Hungarian Notation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-6.0/aa260976(v=vs.60)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: With maybe the exception of `cb` (count of bytes) those links cover Systems Hungarian notation.

Comment: Those articles mostly cover systems Hungarian (aside from the one by Charles Simonyi) and are not complete. I'm looking for an up-to-date list of apps Hungarian prefixes or naming guidelines, if such a thing exists.

Comment: Refer to the thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392079/how-do-i-find-a-list-of-hungarian-notation-prefixes